# Press UIbuttton Shows UITextView Frequent

Tags: ios, iphone

Will Request a code if you Press UIbuttton Shows UITextView ، Press Again UIbuttton Shows UITextView Again :/

[image]

Comment: so you want on every pressure on you UiButton there should be separate uitextview on the screen????

Comment: How many `UITextVIew` are you going to display or just two

Comment: @Stttars what you want ?? add textview dynamically or display and hide one by one??

Comment: @ParasJoshi - add textview dynamically

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generator.

Comment: @mstfbsnli add textview Automatic (Infinite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just one int variable in `.h` file like bellow..

```
int AddNote;
```

after just assign 0 in `viewDidLoad:` method like..

```
AddNote = 0;
```

and afterin bellow method just create it..

```
-(IBAction)btnAddTextView:(id)sender
{

    UITextView *txtAddNote=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(AddNote * 180,20, 180, 44)];
    [txtAddNote setBackgroundColor:[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]];
    [txtAddNote setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15]];
    txtAddNote.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    txtAddNote.layer.borderColor= [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    AddNote++;

    txtAddNote.tag = AddNote;
    txtAddNote.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
    txtAddNote.delegate = self;
    txtAddNote.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //    [txtAddNote sizeToFit];
    //    [txtAddNote setClipsToBounds:YES];
    //    [viewTxt setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:txtAddNote];

    [txtAddNote release];
}
```

hope this help you...

Comment: I want to add One txtView1 And have repeatedly

Comment: Thank you for this interest , Succeeded with me CODE ،But do not be copied Style [link](http://s13.postimage.org/ntxi5uief/2012_12_22_03_56_51.png)

Comment: Delirious is the idea (Add Text) :( ،[link](http://s2.postimage.org/khhx6k5cp/Untitled_1.png) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the visibility of your `UITextView`.

This will display the first, then the second, then hide both, then starts again.

```
if (myTextView2.hidden) {
    if (myTextView1.hidden) {
        myTextView1.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        myTextView2.hidden = NO;
    }
}
else {
    myTextView1.hidden = YES;
    myTextView2.hidden = YES;
}
```

If you just want to switch between the first and the second, you can do:

```
if (myTextView1.hidden) {
    myTextView1.hidden = NO;
    myTextView2.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    myTextView1.hidden = YES;
    myTextView2.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: I want to add One myTextView1 And have repeatedly